# how to add event for all elements except which have a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add mouse over event on all elements on the page except which has class "no_inspect",

i want to add this event after loading all page elements, i tried to write it like that:

```
$('*:not(.no_inspect)').mouseover(MouseOverEvent);
```

but its not working, seams something missed.

**UPDATE** Not working means:

The event is attaching to all elements on the page "have no_inspect class or haven't" which is not the behavior i want.

**UPDATE** MouseOverEvent Code:

```
function DIOnMouseOver(evt) {
    element = evt.target;

    // set the border around the element
    element.style.borderWidth = '2px';
    element.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    element.style.borderColor = '#f00';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? Does the event simply not fire? Is the event getting assigned to the wrong elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`mouseover`** event bubbles. Try **`mouseenter`** instead.

Also, why are you applying the styles to **`evt.target`**? Why not 'this'?

```
function DIOnMouseOver(evt) {
    $(this).css({
        border: '2px solid #f00'
    });
}
```

As mentioned by Matchu (in the comments), another way to avoid propagation is to call **`event.stopPropagation()`** within your event handler.

Comment: Or tack evt.stopPropagation() onto the end of your function.

Comment: very strange, when i changed to mouseenter instead of mouseover it worked very well. do you know why mouseover was not working i thought mouse over is the right event in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work, are you sure the mouseover event is not firing for an element that is wrapping the one you are mousing over?

Are you using the latest and greatest version of JQuery. I know older versions had some sort of class bug in the not selector.

You may want to try

```
$('*').not('.no_inspect').mouseover(MouseOverEvent);
```